# useAnimationOnDidUpdate react hook implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, requestanimationframe

So I want to use `requestAnimationFrame` to animate something using react hooks.
I want something small so `react-spring`/`animated`/`react-motion` is a bad choice for me.
I implemented `useAnimationOnDidUpdate` but it is working incorrectly, here is [reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dnveyj?file=hook.js) with details.
What's wrong here: on second click multiplier for animation starts with 1, but should always start with 0 (simple interpolation from 0 to 1).
So I'm trying to understand why the hook saved previous value though I started a new animation loop already.
Here is a full code listing for hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export function useAnimationOnDidUpdate(
  easingName = 'linear',
  duration = 500,
  delay = 0,
  deps = []
) {
  const elapsed = useAnimationTimerOnDidUpdate(duration, delay, deps);
  const n = Math.min(1, elapsed / duration);

  return easing[easingName](n);
}

// https://github.com/streamich/ts-easing/blob/master/src/index.ts
const easing = {
  linear: n => n,
  elastic: n =>
    n * (33 * n * n * n * n - 106 * n * n * n + 126 * n * n - 67 * n + 15),
  inExpo: n => Math.pow(2, 10 * (n - 1)),
  inOutCubic: (t) => t <.5 ? 4 * t * t * t : (t - 1) * (2 * t - 2) * (2 * t - 2) + 1,
};

export function useAnimationTimerOnDidUpdate(duration = 1000, delay = 0, deps = []) {
    const [elapsed, setTime] = useState(0);
    const mountedRef = useRef(false);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            let animationFrame, timerStop, start, timerDelay;

            function onFrame() {
                const newElapsed = Date.now() - start;

                setTime(newElapsed);
                if (newElapsed >= duration) {
                    console.log('>>>> end with time', newElapsed)
                    return;
                }
                loop();
            }

            function loop() {
                animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
            }

            function onStart() {
                console.log('>>>> start with time', elapsed)
                start = Date.now();
                loop();
            }

            if (mountedRef.current) {
                timerDelay = delay > 0 ? setTimeout(onStart, delay) : onStart();
            } else {
                mountedRef.current = true;
            }

            return () => {
                clearTimeout(timerStop);
                clearTimeout(timerDelay);
                cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
            };
        },
        [duration, delay, ...deps]
    );

    return elapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem with this hook is that it doesn't clean up the `elapsedTime` upon completion.

You can resolve this by adding `setTime(0)` to you `onFrame` function when the animation is expected to stop.

Like this:

```
function onFrame() {
  const newElapsed = Date.now() - start;

  if (newElapsed >= duration) {
    console.log('>>>> end with time', newElapsed)
    setTime(0)
    return;
  }

  setTime(newElapsed);
  loop();
}
```

I know it may seem weird that it doesn't reset itself. But bear in mind that your animation is making use of the same hook instance for both easing in and out. Therefore that cleanup is necessary.

**Note:** I've also move the `setTime(newElapsed)` line so that it's after the if statement since this isn't necessary if the `if` statement is true.

**UPDATE:**

To further improve how this works, you could move the `setTime(0)` to the `return` cleanup.

This would mean that you're `onFrame` function changes to:

```
function onFrame() {
  const newElapsed = Date.now() - start;

  if (newElapsed >= duration) {
    console.log('>>>> end with time', newElapsed)
    setTime(0)
    return;
  }

  setTime(newElapsed);
  loop();
}
```

And then update your `return` cleanup for `useAnimationTimerOnDidUpdate` to:

```
return () => {
  clearTimeout(timerStop);
  clearTimeout(timerDelay);
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
  setTime(0);
};
```

I'm assuming that the reason your animation "isn't working properly" was because the component would flash. As far as my testing goes, this update fixes that.

Comment: thanks, I tried this approach - but it doesn't work for me (the main goal is to create smooth animation with this hook - but it is still looks buggy because multiplier is still incorrect, but now there is additional 0 right after 1)

Comment: Your app is set to update every time `multiplier` changes (it's a dependency). It has to get set back to 0 after reaching 1 somewhere. It logically makes sense to set it back there. Regardless of where you set it to reset, it will always log out because the value changes. || Isn't the goal to make sure the effect starts at 0?

Comment: Remember, the console logs whenever `multiplier` changes. The additional `0` right after `1` is because we're specifically resetting the `multiplier` at the end of the loop so that it starts fresh the next time the effect runs. The bug of the effect starting at 1 before changing back to `0` is now resolved. If the animation still isn't working as expected then that is due to a different bug.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more tweaks to improve the performance of your animation.

Comment: I updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dnveyj?file=hook.js with yours cleanup approach, and it is working just fine even without  if (newElapsed >= duration) {
    console.log('>>>> end with time', newElapsed)
    setTime(0)
    return;
  }
thank you very much!